# Any other methods instead of magento cron job

Tags: magento2

Now I am using Magento Cron job for a different purposes, but it's not working properly. Could you tell me any other method?

Comment: 1. depends what You need. 2. If it wont works properly, maybe You should fix problem to make it works? Why it is not working properly

Comment: Sir actually my problem is        SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_int` SET `value` = ? WHERE (entity_id = 100) AND (attribute_id = '99') AND (`store_id` = 0)

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: but still... Can you describe what are you want to do ? Describe? Show code? You should attach as much information as You can (but important ones)..

Comment: I already using a product insert cron job in my magento web site.Now correctly update 4000 above products.But now i got only above error message

Comment: Can you give me your email id i would like to know something about this issue

Comment: Fell free to paste Your code here. Maybe it will help someone else. Maybe someone else will be able to help You if I couldnt ;)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    
    
    <group id="index">

      

        <job name="product_insert" instance="Family\Cron\Cron\Product" method="execute">
  <schedule>00 */8 * * *</schedule>
        </job>

       
    </group>


</config>

Comment: 1. please, just edit Your post and pastle code there, instead os add it as comment. 2. You   add only definition of Cron. Its fine. Please Add also class `Family\Cron\Cron\Product`- there is magic happens